# Сохранение utm-меток при редиректе

Tags: .htaccess

необходимо сохранять utm метки при редиректе. Текущий редирект:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /order\.php 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=555$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /order.php?id=555&promo=sale [R=302,L]
```

На форумах представлена такая конструкция, как $1, но она не работает, точнее не так, как нужно:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /order.php?id=555&promo=sale$1 [R=302,L]
```

ссылка вида https://site.php/order.php?id=555&utm_source=mail =>
редирект на https://site.php/order.php?id=555&promo=sale&utm_source=mail

Answer (score 1):

Решила вопрос немного изменив регулярное выражение - ^(.*)$ и добавив флаг [R=302,QSA,L]